# Бесплатные звонки телефон - браузер

Tags: sip

Подскажите, какую технологию лучше всего использовать для бесплатных звонков(!) телефон-браузер и браузер-браузер.

Пробовал Voximplant, там есть реализация браузер-браузер или телефон-телефон, не особо подходит, остальное платное.

Либо самому реализовывать SIP?

Comment: Скайп? . . . . .

Comment: Скайп уже готовый программный продукт. Мне нужно реализовать подобное только проще, без конференций, списка контактов, авторизации и тд. Просто голосовое/видео соединение

Comment: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/

Comment: Mac не поддерживает данную технологию